# C++ cin didn't get line

Tags: c++, cin

I have a program where I'm specifying the file to be read using cin, so I run the program ./prog < file.txt, but in the following code, cin doesn't grab anything. Could someone explain why line is empty after the code executes?

```
 void Building::build(){
    char mode;
    cin >> mode >> sizeFloors >> numFloors;

    if(mode == 'M')
        readMap(sizeFloors, numFloors);

}
```

^^ this executes fine

```
void Building::readMap(int floorSize, int numFloors){

    string line;
    int curFloor(numFloors - 1);

    while( curFloor >= 0 ){
        cin >> line;

        if(line.empty()){
            cout << "Error: input file too short" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

^^ here line.empty() returns true

this is the input file

```
M
4
1
WWWW
WWWW
WWWW
WWWW
```

so clearly line shouldnt return empty

Comment: Does it return empty on the first run, or after reading in 4 lines. You never decrement `curFloor` so the loop is infinite.

Comment: I have omitted irrelevant code, it returns empty on the first run

Comment: I still don't understand people taking more time to post their code than to compile it with warnings enabled (`g++ -Wall -g` on Linux), then use a debugger (`gdb` on Linux). Learning to debug programs is a valuable skill (more than asking here and there).

Comment: maybe because I ran ddd, saw that line returned empty and said well wtf it should be reading the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When mixing formatted input (i.e., using `operator>>()`) and unformatted input (e.g., `std::getline()`) you need to make sure that you are at a location you are interested in. The formatted input operators stop reading the moment their format is satisfied. For example, reading a character just reads that one character. Any following charactters, e.g., a newline, is left in the input. `std::getline()` stops reading at the first newline received. I guess, after you entered your menu selection you hit newline and this is where `std::getline()` stops (same if the menu selection is in a file on its own).

A typical approach when switching between formatted and unformatted I/O is to skip all leading spaces:

```
std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, line);
```

Alternatively, you can ignore everything up to and including the first newline:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Which approach is used clearly depends on the content of your data. For example, if you want to read code where leading namespace matters skipping up to the first non-whitespace is not an award winning idea. However, in many situations using `std::ws` works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you ...

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
      getline (myfile,line);
      cout << line << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm using cin, not file streams

Answer (score -1):

The `>>` operator, when reading a `std::string` is taking spaces as string separator, see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/operator%3E%3E/).

You might want to use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) instead.

And you might (e.g. on Linux) compile your code with all warnings and debugging information (e.g. with `g++ -Wall -g`) then use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`) to find out what is happening.

I would suggest to `line.clear()` inside the loop.

I also find writing `int curFloor(numFloors - 1);` less readable than `int curFloor = numFloors - 1;`

Comment: Isn't it >>? Nvm, you fixed it

Comment: there are no spaces in the file, each line is text immediately followed by a carriage return. I originally tried getline(cin, line) but that also returned empty

Comment: @JakeLong: what if you use linefeeds or spaces instead of carriage returns? Same behavior or different?